# Comparing spread (dispersion) between samples

Tags: estimation, estimators, variability, dispersion, scale-estimator

***EDIT:*** 
This question has been heavily paraphrased and re-asked in a broader, but better way here: 
[Paired comparison of instruments using different measurement samples](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201190/evaluating-instruments-using-different-measurement-samples)

This is going to be a long one, since it's wrecking my nerves for days now. =)

I have 4 algorithms (A, B, C and D). 
Each outputs an integer as a result of its calculation. Consider them *instruments* with slight variations in *how* they calculate outputs.

That said, I've evaluated all 4 of them, using humans as the "ground truth", since they measure something humans could express too. A single measurement of this "amount" is called a **determination**, and yields a single **determination score**. 
Each determination score ranges from -1.0 to 1.0, showing how aligned each algorithm is with what the humans said to be true. 
For each algorithm, there are **1152** measurements, using the same 16 humans for "ground truth".

I would like to *rank the algorithms' performances* according to the following criteria:

- C1) Average (mean) of all determination scores;
- **C2) Spread (dispersion, variation, scatter) of values.**

The algorithm with the greatest C1) and smallest C2) wins. That algorithm would have the greatest amount of "true" determinations on average (C1), with the smallest inconsistencies in scores, making it the most *consistent* (C2).

My problem is with **C2)**. 
Since I'm comparing spreads across *different* determination-score-distributions, I'm not sure which of the measures to employ. I'm aware that these belong to *estimators of scale* or *estimators of dispersion*. 
Here's the **boxplot** of algorithms A, B, C and D.

[image: Boxplot]

I've gone through a lot of estimators, and devised a list of the *desired properties*:

1. Applicable to variables using **interval scale** and not just
   ratio scale
2. Applicable to variables containing both **negative** and
   **positive** values
3. Insensitive to mean (average) value close to or approaching
   **zero**
4. Insensitive to variables whose mean (average) value can be
   **zero**
5. Invariant (robust) to underlying distribution of the variable
   (i.e. **non-parametric** if possible)
6. Invariant (robust) to a small number of **outliers**
7. Invariant (robust) to **location parameter** (or choice of
   central tendency), skewness or kurtosis of the distribution.

That crosses-out:

- variance
- std. deviation
- coeff. of variation (CV)
- dispersion index (or variance-to-mean ratio)
- interdecile range
- median absolute deviation from median (MADM)
- mean absolute deviation from mean (MAD)

...and leaves (out of those that I can think of):

- IQR
- Quartile coeff. of dispersion (derived from IQR)
- Qn and Sn by Rousseeuw-Croux
- other M-estimators and *stuff I'm not yet very familiar with*.

Here are my **questions**: 
I'm not sure whether I need 7) as a desired property. 
As can be seen from the boxplot, means and medians of algorithms are all different. I'd like to avoid a measure which is affected by this:

1. Could I "uniformly center" the data by subtractions using the mean, would that help?
2. By doing this "leveling" of all 4 means to zero - would it make the MADM and MAD usable?
3. Are there any other robust estimators of scale (dispersion) I could
   use?

To give a **one-liner** of what I *think* I'm looking for:

> Robust, preferably non-parametric estimator of scale (or dispersion),
>   invariant to change in central-tendency (or location), so that it could be used for comparing (dispersion of) samples.

Thanks for ur time and sry for the long post!

---

**EDIT:**
Tnx to German Demidov, I've plotted the **Bland-Altman plot** of A vs. D. 
Could I use those to find the *more dispersed* one?

[image: Bland-Altman plot]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bland–Altman_plot ?

Comment: Tnx for the quick reply. I was not aware of the Bland-Altman plots - how may I compare spreads of score distributions with it?
Let me add that I'm not interested in the level of "agreement" between the methods, see (C1) above as to why. Maybe the QQ plot would be more appropriate, instead?

Comment: @GermanDemidov and others, any ideas as to my previous comment?

Comment: $Q_n$ is good for your purpose. And Lehman-Hodges estimator for the mean. But this solution will not be really accurate =) there is no absolutely accurate robust method (except situations where you know proportion of outliers or true mixed distributions). Also I see that 5 outliers happen recurrently. You can remove them (all methods predict wrongly on this data points).

Comment: Intuitively, `IQR` would give me the easiest way out, wouldn't it? But then again, it would result in A having the smallest dispersion, despite the fact that it has the biggest variance... I'll go with `Qn` and try the `Sn` too.

Comment: IQR has some problems. You need to increase your sample size $\sim$ 2 times to obtain the estimation with the same standard error (comparing to the standard deviation). $Q_n$ and $S_n$ have higher efficiency, but efficiency of $S_n$ is a bit lower than $Q_n$'s.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but why should the sample size of 1152 yield insufficient efficiency? I was looking for the best estimator of dispersion whilst still robust... I'm not sure I understood ur comment regarding IQR vs Qs or Qn. Why would it be incorrect to say A has the smallest dispersion due to lowest IQR? (I'm aware we're dealing with samples instead of populations, but 1152 is plenty of measurements).

Comment: https://wis.kuleuven.be/stat/robust/papers/publications-1993/rousseeuwcroux-alternativestomedianad-jasa-1993.pdf - see Standardized Variance for MAD. I'm not sure that it's the same for IQR. You can try both and then choose the result that you like more.

Comment: I see, I'm familiar with that paper from before and I'll give it a serious go now... tnx so much for ur time! =)

Comment: @GermanDemidov would you post an answer so I can accept it? I'd be glad to do it if it's okay with u.

Comment: I have tried to do it...but may be I could not find the best words for my impression of the approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for me, it is not the best way of ranking. Your means have real values, so (as I understood) C1 will always be satisfied so you will not have to apply C2 selection criteria. Also you should not forget that you have confidence intervals for means, not just point estimations of means: it can be better by chance. So I would look at more traditional ways to measure performance, such as $r^2$, and of course use cross-validation (or train/test approach). Also I would recommend to exclude several outliers that are wrongly estimated by all 4 algorithms.

But, answering the second question, I would recommend to use $Q_n$ or $S_n$. Both of them have nice properties. Somebody can recommend to use Gini's means difference, but it has 0 breakdown point (but it is somewhat "robust" and also has a lot of good properties). As for C1, I would recommend to use Lehman-Hodges estimator.

Comment: I just noticed these several points as additions to an answer by German Demidov:
If by $r^2$ u mean the _coefficient of determination_, I should point out that I am not interested in regression, since the plotted data containts *performance scores* of each algorithm, which you noted correctly. That said, it is not of our interest how well the scores fit a certain model, because the model is unimportant.

As to everything else, I tentatively agree in search for a better answer.

Comment: Using sd you measure the fit to model $y = \alpha$, where $\alpha$ denotes mean. I do not understand why do you need determination scores and why you just can not apply $r^2$ or Bland-Altman plots without "determination scores". I do not what it is since I do not know statistical term with this name, but I assume that you used some heuristical approach to obtain this scores. Why can not you just compare performance of algorithm with the truth without this scores?

Comment: To answer your last question - because the "truth" is not a binary variable (for an algorithm). It has a certain level of "truthfullness" to each measurement. 
To answer you fully, consult my question heavily paraphrased and re-asked in a broader, but better way here:
http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201190/paired-comparison-of-instruments-using-different-measurement-samples

Comment: ... I just noticed that you might be confusing my "determination scores" with "coeff. of determination". If so, beware that the two are completely unrelated - I apologize for this inconvenience.