# Paired comparison of instruments using different measurement samples

Tags: paired-comparisons, estimators, scale-estimator

I have instruments A, B, C and D - I'm in search of the best one.

The problem: 
For illustrative purposes, let's use an example of evaluating the best among the instruments measuring **difference in color** between **cards in a card-pair**. The best instrument is the one which *correctly* measures the greatest number of darker-colored cards.

Each instrument makes $N = 1152$ measurements of *the same* 1152 card-pairs. A card can be *black*, *white* or a gradient of *gray*. 
If the instrument measures both cards as black, the measurement equals **0**. Both white = **0**. Black vs. white = **100**. 30% gray vs. 65% gray = **35**, etc. Let's call this *difference* and hence each measurement, $\Delta_i$. (Notice that it is defined as the *absolute (unsigned)* difference.)

How do we score the measurement as *correct* or *incorrect*? 
We compare it against the "ground truth". In my case, due to certain design limitations and details I shall not go into - "ground truth" is 16 human subjects, each estimating 72 card-pairs. Notice that $16 \cdot 72 = 1152$. 
Humans merely say which of the cards is **darker**. This card is then considered a *correct* response between two cards in a pair.

Back to the instruments - we *score* each instrument measurement as follows: 
If the measurement is *correct*, its **score** equals:

- $ ms_i = +\Delta_i/100 $.

...if *incorrect*, its **score** equals:

- $ ms_i = -\Delta_i/100 $.

In other words, $\Delta_i$ tells us how "certain" an instrument is in declaring a certain card as *darker*. A measurement with a $\Delta_i = 100$ "certainty", if correct, receives a maximum score $ ms_i = +1.0 $. 
If incorrect, it is "severely punished" for being that certain, receiving a minimum $ ms_i = -1.0 $. The principle applies to all other measurements. 
This yields a total of $M = 1152$ scores $(ms_i)$ for each instrument.

My question:

- How do I find the best instrument, in the most statistically correct
  manner?

If possible, I would refrain from solutions that are very mathematically complex; it needs to be both understandable to me, as well as explainable to others in my field - which is IT.

*Note: All $\Delta_i$ attain a value between 0..100 with no attention to the way card-pairs are picked (i.e. we can make no underlying assumption of their distribution). Ideally, card-pairs would be chosen as truly random, but we cannot guarantee it. 

Moreover, important note: each instrument is given an **identical** set of $\Delta$s in an identical order, for the needs of fair comparison.*

---

...***EXTRA:***

> For those of you interested in my approach so far, consider the
>   boxplot of 1152 measurement scores $ms_i$ for each of the instruments:
>
> [image: Boxplot]
>
> In order to correctly declare the best instrument, I need to use an
>   *estimator of location* - the mean would reflect "highest scored instrument on average" pretty good. It's not robust and its *breakdown
>   point* is 0, which is no big deal because the underlying data are actually "grades of accuracy". In order to find the best-graded instrument, I use the mean. (Median is a 50%-trimmed mean, and is not an appropriate measure of accuracy in this case.)
>
> To check instrument's precision and see if it's consistently correct (or incorrect),
>   I need an *estimator of spread* (dispersion). I've gone through a lot
>   of estimators, and devised a list of the *desired properties*:
>
> 1. Applicable to variables using **interval scale** and not just
>      ratio scale
> 2. Applicable to variables containing both **negative** and
>      positive values
> 3. Insensitive to mean (average) value close to or approaching
>      **zero**
> 4. Insensitive to variables whose mean (average) value can be
>      **zero**
> 5. Invariant (robust) to a small number of **outliers** (see boxplot)
> 6. Invariant (robust) to underlying distribution of the variable
>      (i.e. **non-parametric** if possible)
> 7. Invariant (robust) to **asymmetry** of the distribution and **location estimate** (or choice of central tendency, e.g. mean or median, because they differ between instruments; see boxplot)
> 8. Has the best possible **breakdown point**.
>
> That crosses-out:
>
> - variance
> - std. deviation
> - coeff. of variation (CV)
> - dispersion index (or variance-to-mean ratio)
> - interdecile range
> - median absolute deviation from median (MADM)
> - mean absolute deviation from mean (MAD)
>
> ...and leaves (out of those that I can think of):
>
> - $IQR$
> - Quartile coeff. of dispersion (derived from $IQR$)
> - $Q_n$ and $S_n$ by Rousseeuw-Croux
> - (other stuff I'm not yet very familiar with.)
>
> This is where I'm stuck - I would use the mean (for estimating location),
>   and $IQR$, $Q_n$ and $S_n$ (for estimating spread). The "best" instrument has
>   the greatest mean, with the lowest $IQR$, $Q_n$ and $S_n$.
>
> ... is this approach correct or not? =)